# css hover want to display a box

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to create a menu where whenever you hover over a "button" in my menu,it displays some text,but have an issue with doing it in css.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "home.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<div id = "menu">

<a class = "button"><span>222</span></a>
<a class = "button"><span>222</span></a>
<a class = "button"><span>222</span></a>
<a class = "button"><span>222</span></a>
<a class = "button"><span>222</span></a>
<a class = "button"><span>222</span></a>
<a class = "button"><span>222</span></a>
<a class = "button"><span>222</span></a>

</div>
<span class = "box_menu"><p>asfqwqs</p></span>



</body>
</html>
```

css

```
#menu {
width:70%;
height:35px;
margin:0 auto;
border-radius:0px 0px 3px 3px;
box-shadow:1px 2px 3px 2px #1F0000;
}
body{
background-color:#562500;
background:url('image_for_website.jpg') repeat;
}

a.button{
display:inline;
position:relative;
font-size:12px;
font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
color:white;
height:26px;


}
a.button span {
display: block;
line-height: 30px;
border-right:1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
float:left;
width:10%;
padding:3px;
} 
a.button:hover span{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
cursor: pointer;
}
a.box_menu{
position:absolute;
display:none;
width:20px;
border:1px solid #333333;
color:white;
font-size:12px;
font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
background:rgba(2,2,2,0.7);
margin-top:18%;
margin-left:15%;
border:1px solid white;
}
a.box_menu:hover span{
display:block;
}
```

So, whenever i hover over a span from an anchor class button(let's say first one),i want a box of text which is essentially a span with class box_menu to apper.So how do i do it?please help.Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you actually can't achieve that affect by styling a single `<a>` with your current HTML, e.g.

```
.button:nth-child(1):hover + span {}
```

Wouldn't work because it implies that the `<span>` is a sibling of the link when its the container `<div>` that is a sibling. You obviously can have the spans text appear on hover for the entire `<div>` but it sounds like you only want it for one or a few links, if you don't mind this behavior you can use

```
#menu:hover + .box_menu {}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RtK7M/

Comment: And what if i would want to display it while hover for example an element with some id,how do I change that then?

Comment: One way would be to do `#menu:hover + #idhere {}` or do you mean something different?

Comment: Well,i meant that when you hover the 1 specific button(that's why i'm going to specify it with id),i want this box to appear,another button - another box and so on.

Comment: ant another thing is that when i try hovering over a poped up box,it disappears,and i want it to be left

Comment: You would have to change your HTML around - the only way that would work is if you remove the containing `<div>` .. cause you can't "backtrack" up the DOM with CSS yet, no selector exists.

Comment: For the second thing look into using the jQuery [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method its extremely easy to use

Comment: something like this menu on the left on an amazon. I want to achieve that effect http://www.amazon.com/

Comment: I see .. CSS isn't capable of having the `active` menu item stay a different color until the next one is clicked .. you'll definitely need [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

Comment: you can make it like this)but anyway thanx for the help

Comment: another question is why is my menu navigator is slightli away from the top,and even if i specify top:0%,it stil stays there.